# How to bind some variable value in tcl/tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

Let say we have some variable x, initially x=0. 
Whenever x changes its values from 0 to 1, click some button A 
Whenever x changes its values from 1 to 2, click some button B 
Whenever x changes its values from 2 to 0, click some button C 
 ...

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example that updates `x` once a second and uses a [`trace`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm) on the variable to invoke a button press when it's updated, with the specific button depending on the new value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

grid [ttk::button .a -text A -command {puts "Buttom A pushed"} -state active]
grid [ttk::button .b -text B -command {puts "Button B pushed"}]
grid [ttk::button .c -text C -command {puts "Button C pushed"}]

set x 0

proc update_gui {name _ _} {
    upvar $name v
    switch -- $v {
        0 { .c state !active; .a state active; .a invoke }
        1 { .a state !active; .b state active; .b invoke }
        2 { .b state !active; .c state active; .c invoke }
    }
}

proc update_x {} {
    variable x
    set x [expr {($x + 1) % 3}]
    after 1000 update_x
}

trace add variable x write update_gui
after 1000 update_x
```